# OPLON LBL ADC rewrite an http body to clean a value before xml content

Tags: reverse-proxy, adc

In the HTTP body, requests and responses, I need to clean a non xml part at the start of body when passing through LBL ADC Reverse Proxy.

The value to clean is XMLDATA= eg.:

Values in the HTTP body before rewriting:

```
XMLDATA=<myXmlData> ....
...
...
</myXmlData>
```

Expected values after body rewriting in the HTTP body:

```
<myXmlData> ....
...
...
</myXmlData>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an OPLON LBL ADC body rewrite rule that uses a regular expression to clean a firs part of body response. OPLON LBL ADC is a full reverse proxy and you can inspect or modify REQUEST and RESPONSE, HEADER and BODY.

In this case when the regex rule matches with a start string XMLDATA= the rule replace the content in the all other body data exept the start match frase.

```
<rewriteBodyRule name="cleanXmlContents" flow="BOTH">
    <mimeType value="application/xml" fragmentClose="&gt;" fragmentOpen="&lt;"/>
    <regexTag>^XMLDATA\=(.*)</regexTag>
    <replaceTo>$1</replaceTo>
</rewriteBodyRule>
```

Keep in mind! If the HTTP body has compressed by endpoint  (app/web server), you need disable the compression for that request to rewrite a body. OPLON LBL ADC compress a data body for you after rewriting...

You have 2 way to disable compression:
1) disable compression in the app/web server
2) disable compression with a rewrite HEADER rule in the REQUEST HTTP header by OPLON LBL ADC.

For case (2) you can use a Template rule in the OPLON LBL ADC.